# Get error while installing the selenium (python) on windows 11

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

While I am installing the selenium locally, it returns me this below error. So, do you guys exeprience this issue? If yes, how can I fix it?

My laptop is using windows 11 with python 3.9.13

[image: Installing selenium error]

I am looking forward to hearing from you soon

Comment: Why are you using an msys version of Python instead of the normal Windows Python? You don't need to make Windows pretend it's Unix. But with that said: [don't post screenshots of text](/help/how-to-ask). Put the text in your post and then use [code markdown](/markdown) to keep it nice and monospaced.